# De-Serializing an STL map class member

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I am new to boost & boost serialization. I am trying to de-serialize a STL map class member. Here is the code
:

```
...
class Face
{
  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Face &mf);
  friend class boost::serialization::access;

  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /* file_version */){
      ar & mFaceID;
  }

public:
  size_t mFaceID; /*!< an integer value  represents the Face Identification number */
  void setFaceId(const size_t& faceID)
  {
     mFaceID = faceID;
  }
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Face &mf)
{
    return os << ' ' << (size_t) mf.mFaceID << ' ';
}
```

Point is a member of the derived class define below.

```
...
class Point
{
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Point &p);

  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    // save/load base class information
    ar & X & Y & Z;
  }

public:
  double X, Y, Z;

  Point(double X, double Y, double Z)
  : X(X), Y(Y), Z(Z)
  {}
};
```

Derived class of Face

```
...
class Bend : public Face
{
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Bend &br);

  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
      // save/load base class information
      ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Face>(*this);
      ar & mBendAngle & mBendDirection;
      ar & bendLinePnt & bendLineDir;
  }
public:
  double mBendAngle;
  size_t mBendDirection;
  Point bendLinePnt, bendLineDir;

  Bend(const size_t& faceID, double angle, size_t b_dir, Point pnt, Point dir);
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Bend &mb)
{
  os << mb.mBendAngle << " " << mb.mBendDirection << " " << mb.bendLinePnt.X << " " << mb.bendLinePnt.Y << " " << mb.bendLinePnt.Z;
  os << mb.bendLineDir.X << " " << mb.bendLineDir.Y << " " << mb.bendLineDir.Z;
  os << '\n';

  return os;
}

Bend::Bend(const size_t& faceID, double angle, size_t b_dir, Point pnt, Point dir)
  : mBendAngle(angle), mBendDirection(b_dir), bendLinePnt(pnt), bendLineDir(dir)
{
  setFaceId(faceID);
}
```

This class contains the map that I would like to de-serialize :

```
...
class Model
{
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Model &m);

  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive &ar, Bend& bend, const unsigned int version)
  {
      ar & bends;
  }

public:
  std::map<const size_t, Bend> bends; // THIS IS THE MAP

  void addBend(const Bend& bend);

  void init();
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Model &m)
{
  for(auto it = m.bends.begin(); it != m.bends.end(); it++){
      os << it->first << it->second;
  }

  return os;
}

void Model::addBend(const Bend& bend)
{
  bends.insert({bend.mFaceID, bend});
}

void Model::init()
{
  size_t faceID = 1;
  size_t dir = 0;

  Bend b1(faceID, 90, dir, Point(2, 4, 5), Point(3,5,6));
  addBend(b1);

  ++faceID;
  Bend b2(faceID, 90, dir + 1, Point(2, 4, 5), Point(3,5,6));
  addBend(b2);

  ++faceID;
  Bend b3(faceID, 90, dir, Point(2, 4, 5), Point(3,5,6));
  addBend(b3);

  ++faceID;
  Bend b4(faceID, 90, dir + 1, Point(2, 4, 5), Point(3,5,6));
  addBend(b4);
}
```

Class Usage :

```
#include "model.h"

void save(const Model &m, const char * filename)
{
  std::ofstream ofs(filename);
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
  oa << m;
}

void restore(Model &m, const char * filename)
{
    // open the archive
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);

    // restore the model from the archive
    ia >> m;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  auto test = std::make_unique<Model>();
  test->init();

  save(*test, "text_file.txt");

  auto test2 = std::make_unique<Model>();
  restore(*test2, "text_file.txt");

  return 0;
}
```

The serialization process works Ok I need help with the restore() function or improvements on my code. When I run the code I get a long list of errors such as :

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:37,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:45,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp:24,
                 from face.h:9,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::serialization::access::construct(T*) [with T = std::pair<const long unsigned int, Bend>]’:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:92:22:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::load_construct_data(Archive&, T*, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; T = std::pair<const long unsigned int, Bend>]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:148:24:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::load_construct_data_adl(Archive&, T*, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; T = std::pair<const long unsigned int, Bend>]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/detail/stack_constructor.hpp:51:54:   required from ‘boost::serialization::detail::stack_construct<Archive, T>::stack_construct(Archive&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; T = std::pair<const long unsigned int, Bend>]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/map.hpp:60:48:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::load_map_collection(Archive&, Container&) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; Container = std::map<const long unsigned int, Bend>]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/map.hpp:89:24:   required from ‘void boost::serialization::load(Archive&, std::map<Key, Type, Compare, Allocator>&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; Type = Bend; Key = const long unsigned int; Compare = std::less<const long unsigned int>; Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const long unsigned int, Bend> >]’
/usr/include/boost/serialization/split_free.hpp:58:13:   [ skipping 22 instantiation contexts, use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to disable ]
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:626:18:   required from ‘void boost::archive::load(Archive&, T&) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive; T = Model]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:67:22:   required from ‘void boost::archive::detail::common_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(T&) [with T = Model; Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp:70:9:   required from ‘void boost::archive::basic_text_iarchive<Archive>::load_override(T&) [with T = Model; Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp:82:52:   required from ‘void boost::archive::text_iarchive_impl<Archive>::load_override(T&) [with T = Model; Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:68:9:   required from ‘Archive& boost::archive::detail::interface_iarchive<Archive>::operator>>(T&) [with T = Model; Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive]’
main.cpp:17:11:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:130:9: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<const long unsigned int, Bend>::pair()’
         ::new(t)T;
         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iomanip:40,
                 from face.h:2,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:436:9: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... _Args1, long unsigned int ..._Indexes1, class ... _Args2, long unsigned int ..._Indexes2> std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>)’
         pair(tuple<_Args1...>&, tuple<_Args2...>&,
         ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:436:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:37,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:45,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp:24,
                 from face.h:9,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:130:9: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 0 provided
         ::new(t)T;
         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iomanip:40,
                 from face.h:2,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:375:9: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... _Args1, class ... _Args2> std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>)’
         pair(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<_Args1...>, tuple<_Args2...>);
         ^~~~

/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:360:12: note: candidate: ‘template<class _U1, class _U2, typename std::enable_if<(std::_PCC<((! std::is_same<const long unsigned int, _U1>::value) || (! std::is_same<Bend, _U2>::value)), const long unsigned int, Bend>::_MoveConstructiblePair<_U1, _U2>() && std::_PCC<((! std::is_same<const long unsigned int, _U1>::value) || (! std::is_same<Bend, _U2>::value)), const long unsigned int, Bend>::_ImplicitlyMoveConvertiblePair<_U1, _U2>()), bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_U1, _U2>&&)’
  constexpr pair(pair<_U1, _U2>&& __p)
            ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:360:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:37,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:45,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp:24,
                 from face.h:9,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:130:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
         ::new(t)T;
         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iomanip:40,
                 from face.h:2,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:350:21: note: candidate: ‘template<class _U1, class _U2, typename std::enable_if<(_MoveConstructiblePair<_U1, _U2>() && (! _ImplicitlyMoveConvertiblePair<_U1, _U2>())), bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, _U2&&)’
  explicit constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y)
                     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:350:21: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:37,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:45,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp:24,
                 from face.h:9,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:130:9: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
         ::new(t)T;
         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iomanip:40,
                 from face.h:2,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:341:12: note: candidate: ‘template<class _U1, class _U2, typename std::enable_if<(_MoveConstructiblePair<_U1, _U2>() && _ImplicitlyMoveConvertiblePair<_U1, _U2>()), bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, _U2&&)’
  constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y)
          ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iomanip:40,
                 from face.h:2,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:332:17: note: candidate: ‘template<class _U2, typename std::enable_if<_CopyMovePair<false, const long unsigned int, _U2>(), bool>::type <anonymous> > std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const _T1&, _U2&&)’
        explicit pair(const _T1& __x, _U2&& __y)
                 ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:332:17: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:37,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:45,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp:24,
                 from face.h:9,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:130:9: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
         ::new(t)T;
         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iomanip:40,
                 from face.h:2,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:325:18: note: candidate: ‘template<class _U2, typename std::enable_if<_CopyMovePair<true, const long unsigned int, _U2>(), bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const _T1&, _U2&&)’
        constexpr pair(const _T1& __x, _U2&& __y)
                  ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:325:18: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:37,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:45,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp:24,
                 from face.h:9,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:130:9: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
         ::new(t)T;
         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iomanip:40,
                 from face.h:2,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:318:27: note: candidate: ‘template<class _U1, typename std::enable_if<_MoveCopyPair<false, _U1, Bend>(), bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, const _T2&)’
        explicit constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, const _T2& __y)
                           ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:318:27: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:37,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:45,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp:24,
                 from face.h:9,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:130:9: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
         ::new(t)T;
         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iomanip:40,
                 from face.h:2,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:311:18: note: candidate: ‘template<class _U1, typename std::enable_if<_MoveCopyPair<true, _U1, Bend>(), bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, const _T2&)’
        constexpr pair(_U1&& __x, const _T2& __y)
                  ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:311:18: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:37,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:45,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp:24,
                 from face.h:9,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:130:9: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
         ::new(t)T;
         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iomanip:40,
                 from face.h:2,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:304:17: note: candidate: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&&) [with _T1 = const long unsigned int; _T2 = Bend]’
       constexpr pair(pair&&) = default;
                 ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:304:17: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:303:17: note: candidate: ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const long unsigned int; _T2 = Bend]’
       constexpr pair(const pair&) = default;
                 ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:303:17: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:300:21: note: candidate: ‘template<class _U1, class _U2, typename std::enable_if<(std::_PCC<((! std::is_same<const long unsigned int, _U1>::value) || (! std::is_same<Bend, _U2>::value)), const long unsigned int, Bend>::_ConstructiblePair<_U1, _U2>() && (! std::_PCC<((! std::is_same<const long unsigned int, _U1>::value) || (! std::is_same<Bend, _U2>::value)), const long unsigned int, Bend>::_ImplicitlyConvertiblePair<_U1, _U2>())), bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_U1, _U2>&)’
  explicit constexpr pair(const pair<_U1, _U2>& __p)
                     ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:300:21: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:37,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:45,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp:24,
                 from face.h:9,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:130:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
         ::new(t)T;
         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iomanip:40,
                 from face.h:2,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:291:19: note: candidate: ‘template<class _U1, class _U2, typename std::enable_if<(std::_PCC<((! std::is_same<const long unsigned int, _U1>::value) || (! std::is_same<Bend, _U2>::value)), const long unsigned int, Bend>::_ConstructiblePair<_U1, _U2>() && std::_PCC<((! std::is_same<const long unsigned int, _U1>::value) || (! std::is_same<Bend, _U2>::value)), const long unsigned int, Bend>::_ImplicitlyConvertiblePair<_U1, _U2>()), bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_U1, _U2>&)’
         constexpr pair(const pair<_U1, _U2>& __p)
                   ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:291:19: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/boost/serialization/extended_type_info_typeid.hpp:37,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:45,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_iarchive.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/common_iarchive.hpp:23,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/basic_text_iarchive.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/include/boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp:24,
                 from face.h:9,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/access.hpp:130:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
         ::new(t)T;
         ^~~~~~~~~
         ^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/string:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/8/iomanip:40,
                 from face.h:2,
                 from bend.h:1,
                 from model.h:1,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:242:26: note: candidate: ‘template<class _U1, class _U2, typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::is_default_constructible<_Tp>, std::is_default_constructible<_Dp>, std::__not_<std::__and_<std::__is_implicitly_default_constructible<_U1>, std::__is_implicitly_default_constructible<_U2> > > >::value, bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair()’
       explicit constexpr pair()
                          ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:242:26: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:241:59: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, bool>’
                                    ::value, bool>::type = false>
                                                           ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:229:26: note: candidate: ‘template<class _U1, class _U2, typename std::enable_if<std::__and_<std::__is_implicitly_default_constructible<_U1>, std::__is_implicitly_default_constructible<_U2> >::value, bool>::type <anonymous> > constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair()’
       _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR pair()
                          ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:229:26: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_pair.h:227:59: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, bool>’
                                    ::value, bool>::type = true>
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text - you can just copy & paste the text itself and it'll be much more legible. More importantly, people can then copy and paste it themselves, for example when searching some resource for an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You... never added serialization code. Look for the pattern:

```
class Face {
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned) {
class Point {
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned) {
class Bend : public Face {
    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned) {
class Model {
     template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, Bend& bend, unsigned) {
```

You can probably spot what's wrong. Why is there a `Bend&` in the argument list? It's not used. That should also tell you something.

Fixing:

```
template <class Archive>
void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned) {
    ar& bends;
}
```

Then it fails at:

```
static void construct(T * t){
    // default is inplace invocation of default constructor
    // Note the :: before the placement new. Required if the
    // class doesn't have a class-specific placement new defined.
    ::new(t)T;
}
```

So you either need to [load/save construct data](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#constructors) OR you have to make a default constructor. I'll do the latter because it's simpler.

```
Bend(const size_t& faceID = 0, double angle = 0, size_t b_dir = 0, Point pnt = {}, Point dir = {});
```

This has a ripple effect:

```
Point(double X = 0, double Y = 0, double Z = 0) : X(X), Y(Y), Z(Z) {}
```

Now it compiles. The archive looks like:

```
22 serialization::archive 18 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 9.00000000000000000e+01 0 0 0 2.00000000000000000e+00 4.00000000000000000e+00 5.00000000000000000e+00 3.00000000000000000e+00 5.00000000000000000e+00 6.00000000000000000e+00 2 2 9.00000000000000000e+01 1 2.00000000000000000e+00 4.00000000000000000e+00 5.00000000000000000e+00 3.00000000000000000e+00 5.00000000000000000e+00 6.00000000000000000e+00 3 3 9.00000000000000000e+01 0 2.00000000000000000e+00 4.00000000000000000e+00 5.00000000000000000e+00 3.00000000000000000e+00 5.00000000000000000e+00 6.00000000000000000e+00 4 4 9.00000000000000000e+01 1 2.00000000000000000e+00 4.00000000000000000e+00 5.00000000000000000e+00 3.00000000000000000e+00 5.00000000000000000e+00 6.00000000000000000e+00
```

### Roundtripping

A good sanity check is usually to roundtrip:

```
int main() {
    {
        Model test;
        test.init();

        save(test, "text_file.txt");
    }

    {
        Model roundtrip;

        restore(roundtrip, "text_file.txt");
        save(roundtrip, "roundtrip.txt");
    }
}
```

And indeed the files check out:

```
md5sum text_file.txt roundtrip.txt 
13e472083bff9f51cf05a7c800d2e2bf  text_file.txt
13e472083bff9f51cf05a7c800d2e2bf  roundtrip.txt
```

### Full Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2746c729d843a914)**

```
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Face {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Face& mf);
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned) {
        ar & mFaceID;
    }

  public:
    size_t mFaceID; /*!< an integer value  represents the Face Identification
                       number */
    void setFaceId(const size_t& faceID) { mFaceID = faceID; }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Face& mf) {
    return os << ' ' << (size_t)mf.mFaceID << ' ';
}

class Point {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Point& p);

    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned) {
        // save/load base class information
        ar & X & Y & Z;
    }

  public:
    double X, Y, Z;

    Point(double X = 0, double Y = 0, double Z = 0) : X(X), Y(Y), Z(Z) {}
};

class Bend : public Face {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Bend& br);

    template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned) {
        // save/load base class information
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<Face>(*this);
        ar & mBendAngle  & mBendDirection;
        ar & bendLinePnt & bendLineDir;
    }

  public:
    double mBendAngle;
    size_t mBendDirection;
    Point bendLinePnt, bendLineDir;

    Bend(const size_t& faceID = 0, double angle = 0, size_t b_dir = 0, Point pnt = {}, Point dir = {});
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Bend& mb) {
    os << mb.mBendAngle << " " << mb.mBendDirection << " " << mb.bendLinePnt.X
       << " " << mb.bendLinePnt.Y << " " << mb.bendLinePnt.Z;
    os << mb.bendLineDir.X << " " << mb.bendLineDir.Y << " "
       << mb.bendLineDir.Z;
    os << '\n';

    return os;
}

Bend::Bend(const size_t& faceID, double angle, size_t b_dir, Point pnt, Point dir)
        : mBendAngle(angle), mBendDirection(b_dir), bendLinePnt(pnt), bendLineDir(dir)
{
    setFaceId(faceID);
}

class Model {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Model& m);

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned) {
        ar & bends;
    }

  public:
    std::map<size_t, Bend> bends; // THIS IS THE MAP
    void addBend(const Bend& bend);
    void init();
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Model& m) {
    for (auto it = m.bends.begin(); it != m.bends.end(); it++) {
        os << it->first << it->second;
    }

    return os;
}

void Model::addBend(const Bend& bend) { bends.insert({ bend.mFaceID, bend }); }

void Model::init() {
    size_t faceID = 1;
    size_t dir = 0;

    Bend b1(faceID, 90, dir, Point(2, 4, 5), Point(3, 5, 6));
    addBend(b1);

    ++faceID;
    Bend b2(faceID, 90, dir + 1, Point(2, 4, 5), Point(3, 5, 6));
    addBend(b2);

    ++faceID;
    Bend b3(faceID, 90, dir, Point(2, 4, 5), Point(3, 5, 6));
    addBend(b3);

    ++faceID;
    Bend b4(faceID, 90, dir + 1, Point(2, 4, 5), Point(3, 5, 6));
    addBend(b4);
}

//#include "model.h"
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <fstream>

void save(const Model& m, std::string filename) {
    std::ofstream ofs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << m;
}

void restore(Model& m, std::string filename) {
    // open the archive
    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);

    // restore the model from the archive
    ia >> m;
}

int main() {
    {
        Model test;
        test.init();

        save(test, "text_file.txt");
    }

    {
        Model roundtrip;

        restore(roundtrip, "text_file.txt");
        save(roundtrip, "roundtrip.txt");
    }
}
```