# Boost de-serialized Object has nan or -nan values

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I recently asked about de-serialization a map for which I got an answer here : [De-Serializing an STL map class member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62524374/de-serializing-an-stl-map-class-member)
The problem I am now face is that I get `nan` values for some `Point` object values. Here is a sample serialized string :

```
22 serialization::archive 16 0 0 47 uploads/guest/another_project/90.step_1/90.step 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 9.00000000000000000e+01 1 0 0 -2.400000000000000000000e+01 1.000000000000000000000e+00 -2.500000000000000000000e+01 -2.400000000000000000000e+01 1.000000000000000000000e+00 2.500000000000000000000e+01
```

I decided to print the values during serialization and de-serialization and the correct values are displayed.

```
...
class Point
{
  friend class boost::serialization::access;
  friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Point &p);

  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
    // save/load base class information
    ar & X & Y & Z;

    std::cout << "(" << X << ", " << Y << ", " << Z << ")" << std::endl; // OK
  }
...
};
```

Operations on the `Point` objects return inf/nan/incorrect results so I decided to print the `Point` objects in another function and instead of getting `Point` values such as `(-24, 1, -25) & (-24, 1, 25)` I am getting `(-nan, -nan, -nan) & (-nan, -nan, nan)`

I have 2 Point objects startp and endp in the `Bend` class Which are serialized as follows :

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    // save/load base class information
     ar & boost::serialization::base_object<MFace>(*this);
     ar & mBendAngle & mBendDirection & startp & endp;
}
```

There is another object called bendline that I have to create using the 2 `Point` objects : This is the function where i print the points

```
  void ModelBend::makeBendLine(){
    gp_Pnt endPoint(
      startp.X,
      startp.Y,
      startp.Z
    );

    gp_Pnt dirVertex(
      startp.X - endp.X,
      startp.Y - endp.Y,
      startp.Z - endp.Z
    );

    bendLine_ = gp_Lin(endPoint, gp_Dir(dirVertex.X(), dirVertex.Y(), dirVertex.Z()));
    
    std::cout << "==========================================="  << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(" << startp.X << ", " << startp.Y << ", " << startp.Z << ")" << " ==== ";
    std::cout << "(" << endp.X << ", " << endp.Y << ", " << endp.Z << ")" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "==========================================="  << std::endl;
  }
```

This function is called from the ModelBend constructor. This is where I get nan values for **SOME** Point values.

Comment: So your printing from `serialize` says you are **not** getting nan from serialization/deserialization but your question title says that you are. I'm a bit confused. Surely the evidence is that you have a bug elsewhere in your program.

Comment: @john I wasn't sure how I would present it. How is it now?

Comment: My point is that there's no evidence that the serialization or deserialization is the problem (in fact the evidence is the opposite). Based on what you've presented here it just seems you have a bug somewhere else in your code. But without being able to see the rest of your code it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 1):

I changed my code and called makeBendLine() from the serialization function and not in the constructor ModelBend() as shown below and now everything works perfect :

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    // save/load base class information
     ar & boost::serialization::base_object<MFace>(*this);
     ar & mBendAngle & mBendDirection & startp & endp;

     makeBendLine();  // LIKE THIS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to execute the function when serializing?

Probably not.
For that you have the `is_saving/is_loading` trait.

```
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    // save/load base class information
     ar & boost::serialization::base_object<MFace>(*this);
     ar & mBendAngle & mBendDirection & startp & endp;

     if(Archive::is_loading::value) makeBendLine();
}
```

(The real problem is that makeBendLine could be touching memory for a save operation that is nominally `const`.)